# Como encaminhar uma página com mascaramento sem criar um iframe?

Tags: html, ssh

Comprei um domínio ontem no GoDaddy, e estou redirecionando o site com mascaramento para um servidor que fiz, só que ele está criando um iframe por cima e não consigo ver o caminho do site, sempre fica no mesmo domínio mesmo em páginas diferentes.

Comment: Coloque o código que você tentou para poder ajudar de forma efetiva.

Comment: <html>

<head>
  <title>GRZS </title>
  <META name="description" content="UAAAA">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://35.192.59.105/" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 11 -->
<!-- -->
</html>

Comment: Coloque na pergunta, editando.